# Bug with tuple and Typed views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Got a werid problem with a view, if i define it with

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Tuple<string, DateTime?, double?, double?, double?>>>"
```

i get the werid error:

```
CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
Line 118:    public class views_report_intrestcalc_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Tuple<string, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
```

But it workes perfectly if i remove the last ", double?". A bug in the asp.net comiller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code the ASP.NET compiler generates is broken for your example. I can re-create this (Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, ASP.NET MVC 2) and get:

```
public class views_home_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Tuple<string,
        System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
    private static bool @__initialized;
    ...
```

When it should be:

```
public class views_home_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Tuple<string,
        DateTime?, double?, double?, double?>>>, 
        System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState,
        System.Web.IHttpHandler {
    private static bool @__initialized;
    ...
```

**Apparently, there's a limit to the amount of [abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626167/bug-with-tuple-and-typed-views/3626687#3626687) it can take.**

Answer (score 2):

While I have no idea why your code doesn't compile (it looks right) instead of using a `Tuple` I would **strongly** recommend you using a view model (probably even the compiler chokes on the ugliness :-)):

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<MyViewModel>>"
```

Having:

```
<%: Model.Username %>
<%: Model.Date %>
```

is **far more readable** than:

```
<%: Model.Item1 %>
<%: Model.Item2 %>
```